# after successfully installation of jhipster i am getting 'jhipster' is not recognized as an internal or external command,

Tags: jhipster

problem >>   'jhipster' is not recognized as an internal or external command,
operable program or batch file.

Steps >>

1. Install Java 8
2. Install Node.js
3. install Yarn
4. install Yeoman: yarn global add yo
5. Install JHipster: 
   yarn global add generator-jhipster and yarn add generator-jhipster

after i try to start jhipster i am getting error.

Error1 >>
C:\Users\zycus>jhipster
'jhipster' is not recognized as an internal or external command,
operable program or batch file.

Error2>>
C:\Users\zycus>yo jhipster
'yo' is not recognized as an internal or external command,
operable program or batch file.

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/PDXMn.png)

Answer (score 3):

Maybe you did not restart your Command prompt or your Windows session after having installed yarn and so your command path has not been updated.

Look at your `PATH` environment variable and ensure it includes the location returned by `yarn global bin`. This is where the `jhipster.cmd` file (and other global node binaries) must have been installed.

Answer (score 0):

In newer versions of jhipster this will likely be an issue with `npm` not being in your PATH. I was able to resolve this issue by running this command:

```
export PATH=$PATH:/c/Users/[MY_USER]/AppData/Roaming/npm/
```

I found the correct folder by searching for `jhipster.cmd` from my user root folder.